# Using Lagrange equation

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, vectors, coordinate-systems

In classical mechanics we have a concept of generalized coordinates. 
Say my generalized coordinates are $(x,y)$.
My doubt is, Is it legal to write the position vector in any vector basis say polar basis but having components which are functions of $x$, $y$ and then use the Lagrange equation?
$$\vec r = f(x,y) \hat e_r + g(x,y) \hat e_\theta$$

Comment: What "Lagrange equation" do you have in mind? If you mean Euler-Lagrange equations $$ \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial u^a} - \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \dot u^a} = 0$$ they don't operate on vector quantities...

Comment: Yes those ones you mentioned, although they don't directly work on vectors they can be derived from vectors, like we can take dot product of v.v and get v^2.

Comment: I still don't get what you have a problem with. Lagrangian is a scalar function; you can excpress it using any coordinates you want, assuming you properly transform all positions and velocities. At this point any vector space structure of the position space becomes irrelevant. You just use the formula above to derive the equations of motion. Can you give an example of a computation whose validity you want to confirm (not in a comment, edit the question)

Answer (score 2):

It needs to be remembered that the vector basis in polar coordiantes depends on the point at which it is calculated.

The position vector in respect to the origin of the system of coordiantes in polar coordinates always has only the radial component:
$$ \vec{r} = r\hat e_r = r(x,y) \hat e_r(x,y)$$
where $$r(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$ 
$$ \hat e_r(x,y) = \frac{x\hat e_x + y\hat e_y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
However, if you calculate the position of one point in respect to the position of another point, the vector may have other components:
$$ \vec r_{12} = \vec r_1 - \vec r_2 = r(x_1,y_1) \hat e_r(x_1,y_1) - r(x_2,y_2) \hat e_r(x_2,y_2) = $$ $$= a(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2) \hat e_r(x_2,y_2)  + b(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2) \hat e_\theta(x_2,y_2) $$
where
$$ \hat e_\theta(x,y) = \frac{-y\hat e_x + x\hat e_y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
$$ a(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2) = \frac{x_1x_2+y_1y_2}{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2}} - \sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2} $$
$$ b(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2) = \frac{-x_1y_2+y_1x_2}{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2}} $$
thus quantities like velocity, acceleration, force, etc. may have nonzero angular components in radial coordinates.

As for the Lagrange equation, I don't really know what equation do you mean.

Answer (score 2):

If one decides for a certain coordinate set used in a Lagrangian, everything should be expressed in these coordinates. Actually, this is very easy to achieve. Let's assume we only have a kinetic term in the Lagrangian (the dot expresses the $t$-derivative of the variable)

$$L = \frac{m}{2}(\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2)$$

This Lagrangian is expressed in cartesian coordinates. If you want to express it in polar coordinates, both cartesian coordinates $(x,y)$ are expressed by the polar ones $(r,\phi)$:

$$ x = r\cos \phi \quad \text{and} \quad y=r\sin \phi$$

For the computation of $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$ one has to compute the differentials:

$$dx = \cos\phi dr -r \sin\phi d\phi \quad \text{and}\quad dy=\sin\phi dr + r\cos\phi d\phi$$

and enter them in $\frac{dz}{dt} \equiv \dot{z}$ where $z=x$ or $z=y$. At the end one gets:

$$L =\frac{m}{2}(\dot{r}^2 + r^2\dot{\phi}^2)$$

So the Lagrangian is expressed completely in the new coordinates. Actually, this is done always in axisymmetric problems. The Lagrangian should always clearly express that it has only 2 degrees of freedom $(x,y)$ or $(r,\phi)$. If one starts mixing different coordinates, then one gets hidden dependencies of expressions on the new (res. old) coordinates which make then the differentiation of the Lagrangian error-prone. Actually it happens for instance when one writes:

$$L = \frac{m}{2}(\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2 + \dot{z}^2) - \frac{k}{r}$$

But upon writing down the Lagrange-Euler equations, $L$ has to be differentiated according to one chosen set of coordinates (and their derivatives) and if it is not done properly it leads to wrong results.

Answer (score 2):

Your question “ Is it legal to write the position vector in any vector basis say polar basis but having components which are functions $x,y$ and then use the Lagrange equation?“ this  is illegal.you have to decide which generalized coordinates you want to use.

I thing you better solve this problem using polar coordinates

You have to write your Position vector with polar coordinates.

With:
$$\vec{R}=\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{pmatrix}=r\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \left( \varphi \right)  \\
sin\left( \varphi \right) 
\end{pmatrix}$$

And

$$\begin{aligned}\overrightarrow{e}_{r}=\frac{1}{||\vec{R}||}\frac{\partial \vec{R}}{\partial r}=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \left( \varphi \right)  \\
\sin\left( \varphi \right) 
\end{pmatrix}\\
\overrightarrow{e }_{\varphi }=\frac{1}{||\vec{R}||}\frac{\partial \vec{R}}{\partial \varphi}==\begin{pmatrix}
-\sin\left( \varphi \right)  \\
\cos\left( \varphi \right) 
\end{pmatrix}\end{aligned}$$

Thus the position vector is $$\overrightarrow{R}=f\left( r,\varphi \right) \begin{pmatrix}
\cos \left( \varphi \right)  \\
\sin \left( \varphi \right) 
\end{pmatrix}+g\left( r,\varphi \right) \begin{pmatrix}
-\sin\left( \varphi \right)  \\
\cos \left( \varphi\right) 
\end{pmatrix}$$

The kinetic energy is:

$$T=\frac{m}{2}\vec{v}^T\,\vec{v}$$
Where
$$\begin{aligned}
\overrightarrow{v}=\dfrac{\partial \overrightarrow{R}}{\partial \overrightarrow{q}}\dfrac{d\overrightarrow{q}}{dt}\\
\overrightarrow{q}=\begin{pmatrix}
r \\
\varphi 
\end{pmatrix}\end{aligned}$$

The potential energy is

$$U=-\frac{k}{\sqrt{\vec{R}^T\,\vec{R}}}$$